# Calendar and contacts sync using "Server" account type

Tags: contacts, sync, calendar

Device: Galaxy S4
Android: 4.2.2

I have been looking through the `Settings  > Accounts > Add account` menu and found there is an entry called "Server" that seems to allow you to sync calendar and contacts from a private server. Does anyone know how this works? I have tried pointing it at my OwnCloud server but cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an account for syncing via SyncML, a protocol used by (e.g.) funambol.

In a test, I've already managed to sync some events using syncevolution as http-server, but currently I'm not sure, wether SSL connections work as well. (I've even started a question on that topic.)